# Aligning case equations, while text on left ... argh!

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, alignment, alignat

I'm strugling with an alignment case which I don't usually use.  See the MWE below and its preview:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{align}
    &\text{For $x = 1$ :}
    & y &= A.
    \\[1em]
    &\text{For $x = 0$ :}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= B, \\[1ex]
        z &= C.
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview with issue shown in red:

[image]

This code has two issues (at least!):

1. The space indicated with the red? is too tight and the text parts should be closer to the left margin.
2. All equal signs should be aligned.

I guess I need to use a `split` or an `alignat` environment, but I don't see how to get it right.  The left brice is what gives me the main trouble.  I need a suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

Meow?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{align}
    \text{For $x = 1$}\colon
    &\hphantom{\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
       {\,}\\
        {\,}
    \end{aligned}
    \right.}y = A. &&
    \\[1em]
    \text{For $x = 0$}\colon&
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= B, \\[1ex]
        z &= C.
    \end{aligned} 
    \right. &&
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally use `fleqn` throughout all my documents.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{align}
    \text{For $x = 1$}\colon
    &\hphantom{\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
       {\,}\\
        {\,}
    \end{aligned}
    \right.}y = A. 
    \\[1em]
    \text{For $x = 0$}\colon&
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        y &= B, \\[1ex]
        z &= C.
    \end{aligned} 
    \right. 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, an \hphantom trick.  Feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: @Cham The only simpler alternative I'd be aware of is Ti*k*Z + tikzmark.

Comment: MEOW! +1 for this answer.

Comment: What's "`flern`"?  (I suspect `fleqn`, with typing like mine.)

Comment: @Cham Yes. `fleqn` + "autocorrection" = `flern`. CHHH

Comment: I'd say the cat is definitely alive as long as it can meow.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{align}
\text{For } x & = 1: \ \hphantom{\biggl\{}  y  = A.    \\
\text{For } x & = 0: \ \left\{
                        \begin{aligned}
                            y &= B, \\[1ex]
                            z &= C.
                        \end{aligned}
                        \right.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a proper solution.  The case text should be close to the left margin (with some space relative to the main text).  It's almost an itemize list.

Comment: Sory, where is noted this demand in your question?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option with boxes (overlapping and `\phantom`s):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \text{For $x = 1$ :} &&
    y = \mathrlap{\text{long right-hand side}.}\phantom{\text{longest right-hand side,}} \\
  \text{For $x = 0$ :} &&
    ~\left\{\begin{aligned}
      & \text{long LHS} = \text{longest right-hand side,} \\
      & \phantom{\text{long LHS}}\mathllap{z} = C.
    \end{aligned}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

And then a similar one that uses [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to automate the maximum box width collection:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \text{For $x = 1$ :} &&
    y = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{long right-hand side.} \\
  \text{For $x = 0$ :} &&
    ~\left\{\begin{aligned}
      & \eqmakebox[LHS][r]{long LHS} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{longest right-hand side,} \\
      & \eqmakebox[LHS][r]{z} = C.
    \end{aligned}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Both yield the same output:

[image]

In both instances, the aim is to identify the widest element around the alignments and use them to adjust shorter items.